# Invisible text that can be seen only in PDF viewer

Tags: pdf

How to make text that is visible only in PDF viewer and disappears when printing?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The `ocg-p` package might help.

Comment: ‘ocg-p‘ is unmaintained for quite a while now and has some issues. ‘ocgx2‘ can be used as a drop-in replacement, providing the same user commands with some extensions.

Comment: There is now ocgx2 at https://ctan.org/pkg/ocgx2